# How can I permenantally disable one of my integrated graphic cards (ATI)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, infinite-loop

In windows, I would go to Device Manager and disable it. In Ubuntu (Linux), I have no idea.

I want to disable it because it's causing my computer to freeze a few minutes after booting into Linux Live USB.

In Windows it would show a pixelated display, which would clear as soon as I disable it through device manager. Is there something similar in Xubuntu Live USB?

I can't do it through BIOS because that option does not exist in my BIOS.

This started happing after I dropped the laptop. Pressing on it (the keyboard area) would get things to be normal, and then return to bad display as soon as I let go. I guess the hardware came loose.

Anyway, how do I disable it? I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 LTS live USB. I Also have WindowsPE, so if i can do it through there, that would also be great.

What I'd like to know how to do is to either...

a) disable it through Linux Live USB like how it could be disabled through device manager in Windows.

b) prevent it from starting when I boot up into Linux Live USB. So I don't have to disable it every time I boot up (if "a" above doesn't already accomplish this like it doesn't in Windows when disabling through device manager).

I can't boot into Windows (7) normally because I'm stuck in bootloop.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Is the computer really freezing, or is just the display freezing? Can you log in with `ssh` from a second computer? Can you use `Ctrl-Alt-F1` (or whatever your distro uses) to switch to a text console? If any of those work, have a look at the output of `dmesg`. It will tell you which kernel drivers are loaded. You probably need to disable the kernel driver for the ATI card (there are several choices). Doing that will be difficult on a live boot USB stick. And no, you can't disable that on a running system. If you just need to switch the display to the working card, that's easier.

Comment: @dirkt How do I switch to the working one?

Comment: You can't just "switch to the working one", it doesn't work that way on Linux. Sorry. But you can definitely fix that if you make yourself familiar with how it works. And it's difficult for people who know how it works to debug your system by Q&A on a website.